# Can Stack Overflow also get custom badges such as those on User Experience?

Tags: feature-request, design, badges

Or even, since they are badges, which play the same role on all sites, the UX badges could be everywhere. Instead of current dots, which are less cool and less distinguishable for bat-blind people such as myself, since the dots are tiny, without image or texture and identical except for color. I personally have a problem with telling bronze from silver, due to Deuteranomaly.

Stack Overflow and many others:

[image]

[User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

Comment: Different sites have different designs. SO badges are minimalstic. I wouldn't disagree with slightly bigger/flashier badges... but I'm sure plenty other users would. Making any kind of change in a community like this will always be fraught with drama.

Comment: Seems like User Experience has the better user experience.

Comment: @yivi I see you are totally right. A downvote per minute proves your point. But no wonder, it is a crucial issue, and how could someone even suggest such a dramatic change.. :D

Comment: @yivi If I'm not mistaken there was some kind of proposal/discussion here on meta  for cooler badge-icons - let me see if I can find it. Personally I wouldn't mind a little more fanciness in the badge-design either in order to ramp up the gamification-experience..

Comment: As long as I don't notice them I personally don't really care how flashy they look

Comment: Given that questions are supposed to be self-contained on the main sites, I assume that to count on meta sites too. So please edit some examples into your question so that those of us not using UX know what you're talking about.

Comment: Personally I prefer the ones on Stack Overflow to User Experience

Comment: On Code Review you get braces `{}`. Not very sexy either.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow's design came first, so the badges look like...badges.

The design was simple and utilitarian, in keeping with our ethos of a high signal-to-noise ratio and a model that puts focus on *content* rather than accoutrements.

When the network was broadened, and other sites were launched like User Experience, they were given designs that kept the general design of Stack Overflow but altered certain minor aspects of the theme, like colors and badge icons, in order to give these sites their own, distinct identities.

It does not really make sense to now go back and style Stack Overflow differently. We are the original flavor, and the original is always the best.

[image: Coca-Cola Marilyn Monroe advertisement: "They don't make 'em like they used to. We do. Coca-Cola: Original Taste Since 1886"]

Comment: I like the "signal-to-noise ratio" idea.  But doesn't "original is always the best" mean in other words,  that "changes are always for worse"? Anyway, I still have a hard time telling silver from bronze on SO. Not so much on UX. But, whatever.. :)

Comment: "original is always the best" was a bit of a joke. It isn't *always* best. The idea is just to give different sites a different feel/identity. Stack Overflow's is unique because it was the original. Not being able to tell silver from bronze could be fixed by simply adjusting the lightness of the colors to provide additional contrast. That would be a separate feature request. It doesn't seem particularly urgent, since bronze is *always* on the far right, and silver always to its left. @Marko36

Comment: Ok, cool. Btw.  Is there any other site besides UX, which uses badge-like badges instead of dots?  I'm lazy to go through them all..

Comment: I don't have them all memorized, either. Every graduated site has a different design, and many have custom badge icons. Here are a few selected examples: https://movies.stackexchange.com, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com, https://english.stackexchange.com/, https://academia.stackexchange.com/, https://aviation.stackexchange.com/, https://diy.stackexchange.com/, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/, https://security.stackexchange.com/, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: "Coca-Cola once contained an estimated nine milligrams of cocaine per glass. (For comparison, a typical dose or "line" of cocaine is 50–75 mg) In 1903, it was removed." [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca-Cola). So... even they don't make 'em like they used to.